# blenderkit install problem

Tags: add-on, blenderkit

I have Blender 3.4.1 and I'm having trouble installing blenderkit as an add-on.
I have blenderkit-v3.5.2.2.230307 in my download file and it's still zipped.
In edit > preferences > addons > install, I click on blenderkit in the explorer and when I click install it shows another blenderkit folder. When I select that and click 'install add-on' it just opens that folder. I even tried selecting all of the items.
[image: from downloads]

[image: blenderkit folder]
[image: expanded folder that doesn't install]

Comment: Your download folder should just show the blenderkit zip filename (blenderkit-v3.5.2.230307.zip), but it appears to show a folder with that name. Normally you'd just click it once to make the name appear in the bottom Install Add-on line, click the button, and it would install from there without opening any folders. I've just downloaded it from the [Blenderkit web site](https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/) and that's how it appears when I want to install it. (Using Windows 10 here).

Comment: That's what I figured too. But nope, it wants to open the folder. I just installed Blender v3.4.1 so maybe there's a bug.

Comment: That's the version I'm using. Are any of the other files in the folder in your first image Zip files, or are they all folders? I'd try moving the downloaded Blenderkit zip file to your desktop and making sure that Windows (assuming that's what you're running) is showing it as a zip file. If it is, you could try installing from the Desktop in Blender and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later today.

Answer (score 1):

There are known problem with the installation when using the Safari browser, which automatically unzips the downloaded archives, which later causes problems with the installation. It is possible that your browser behaves in similiar manner. Or that the file explorer automatically unzips the zip archive and opens the directory and does not let you to select the zip as it is. (Make sure you are not double clicking the zip, just select it with one click and then click on install/open button.)

As a workaround for all cases you can install the add-on manually:

1. unzip the zip archive, this should create a new directory called "blenderkit" which contains all the add-on files,
2. copy the whole "blenderkit" directory,
3. place the "blenderkit" directory into "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender[version]\addons" or "C:\Users[profile]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\blender[version]\addons".

When you start the Blender, you should see the BlenderKit in the installed add-ons. The whole installation process of Blender is nothing more than just unziping the archive into predefined location. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with my Mac, and it is just like [Andreas says](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290453/145249) with Safari.

My quick fix was just to select the blenderkit map with my right mouse click and compress the map. You will get a ZIP file. Use this ZIP file with the install add-ons in Blender.